# Is it possible to have shell account mailbox along virtual mailboxes in Postfix?

Tags: postfix, mail-forwarding

I've just setup my first virtual mailbox in Postfix. I wonder if it is possible to have two mailboxes on the same server, one virtual and one with shell account, within the same domain?

```
first@mydomain.com => goes to /home/first/..
second@mydomain.com => goes to /var/spool/mail/virtual/..
```

What I need is to forward emails using `.forward` file and it is possible only for shell accounts and not virtual mailboxes. So I need to have both types of mailboxes, one to store and one to forward.

The problem I have is that when I add mydomain.com to `mydestination` list, no email is saved within virtual mailboxes. And ThunderBird prompts:

```
An error occurred while sending mail. The mail server responded:  5.1.1 <second@mydomain.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table. Please check the message recipient second@mydomain.com and try again.
```

**[UPDATE]**

Here's what I've done so far without success:

My `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
mydestination = localhost
virtual_mailbox_domains = mydomain.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/valias
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
```

My `/etc/postfix/valias`:

```
shell_account shell_account@localhost
```

My `/etc/postfix/vmailbox`:

```
virtual@mydomain.com mydomain.com/virtual/
```

And then I've run `postmap /etc/postfix/valias`, `postmap /etc/postfix/vmailbox` and finally `postfix reload`. And since I'm using Courier as for IMAP server, `userdb -show` shows:

```
virtual
```

But when I try to send an email to shell_account@mydomain.com, Thunderbird prompts:

```
An error occurred while sending mail. The mail server responded:  5.1.1 <shell_account@mydomain.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table. Please check the message recipient shell_account@mydomain.com and try again.
```

**[UPDATE]**

And here's my `mail.log`:

```
postfix/smtpd[10098]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
postfix/smtpd[10098]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 <shell_account@mydomain.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<mehran@localhost> to=<shell_account@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[127.0.0.1]>
postfix/smtpd[10098]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

Comment: Yes. Read the docs at postfix.org.

Comment: I'm not saying that I've read it completely. But I'm not a foreigner to it either. The problem is that when I put mydomain.com in `mydestination`, then no email is stored in virtual mailboxes ending with mydomain.com! A pointer to the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know this satisfied your need or not. Suppose

```
mydestination = local.mydomain.com
virtual_mailbox_domains = mydomain.com
```

Then add the alias on your virtual_alias_maps

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias
```

Content of `/etc/postfix/virtual_alias` (updated)

```
second@domain.com second
```

The idea is generate alias from your virtual_mailbox domains to local domain because .forward only works on local domain.

References: [postfix.org](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#in_virtual_other)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work. I've updated the question, would you please take a look at it?

Comment: What's the error says in `maillog` file?

Comment: I've updated the question with logs.

Comment: I found the problem, I needed to write `first@mydomain.com first` in virtual_alias. Thanks.